# Should I store `ImageSource` or instantiate it on demand?

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I'm designing a mechanism similar to Microsoft SDK's `CrispImage`. The idea is to render and cache images from SVGs basing on requested resolution and current DPI. I also need to be able to save and load built cache, so that I won't have to re-render images, which already have been rendered in the future.

Since I'm writing all that for WPF, I subclassed `Image`, which is supposed to be used like following:

```xml
<c:CrispImage Width="16" Height="16" ImageResource="Arrow" />
```

I achieve that by internally binding `Source` property to some other properties:

```cs
public CrispImage()
{
  var sourceBinding = new MultiBinding();
  sourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(Dpi)) });
  sourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(ImageResource)) });
  sourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(Width)) });
  sourceBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(Height)) });
  sourceBinding.Converter = new CrispImageSourceConverter();

  this.SetBinding(SourceProperty, sourceBinding);
}
```

In the end I need to provide image as a `ImageSource` (BitmapSource in my case). And here's where I have the question:

**Can I cache `ImageSource`s or should I create them always on demand from `Bitmap`s, which I keep in memory?**

The reasons, why I ask:

- I don't know, if ImageSource *can* be cached and reused in multiple places?
- Does created `BitmapImageSource` contain inside the `Bitmap`'s instance itself? Or does it copy it? (since I need to keep those `Bitmap`s to save them into cache, I'd end up in having twice as much memory occupied by them)
- If I need to re-create 100 images (for instance to display multiple images on a toolbar), is it fast enough to create all them as `BitmapSource`s from `Bitmap`s on the fly or should I use cached instances instead?

Comment: Did you see the [BitmapCacheOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)?

Comment: Why do you "*need to keep those Bitmaps*", and why do you have (WinForms?) Bitmaps at all? How do you convert from Bitmap to BitmapSource? It does not seem to make much sense to cache BitmapSource objects when you already cache Bitmaps from which the BitmapSources are created.

Comment: Svg are best converted to geometries for use in paths or a drawingimage. You only get fill and stroke for a path. Drawingimage can have multiple geometries each with own brush. It'd be a bit tedious manually doing 100 icons BUT you get a 100% wpf friendly vector result.